# Cómo hacer que ha me muestre texto en vez de mandar una alerta

Tags: javascript

encontré este código  de js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://www.yourprivateserver.com/foo.gif";
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;

img.onload = function()
{
    // If the server is up, do this.
    alert("Server is up!");
}

img.onerror = function()
{
    // If the server is down, do that.
    alert("Server is down!");
}
```

lo estoy incrustando en HTML pero como podría ver se muestr como una alerta, yo quisiera que en vez de alerta se mostrara un texto normal en cada caso desnutro del recuadro donde estoy escribiendo el código. Alguien me puede ayudar con esto? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Alejandro. Para poder ayudarte mejor, pon tu HTML en la pregunta e indica en qué parte del código quieres insertar el texto.

Answer (score 1):

Primero necesitas decidir en qué elemento HTML incluirás el texto. Por ejemplo, si agregas un DIV con un id, puedes usarlo para setearle su contenido utilizando `document.getElementById`:

```html
<div id="miDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://www.yourprivateserver.com/foo.gif";
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;

img.onload = function()
{
    // If the server is up, do this.
    document.getElementById("miDiv").innerText = "Server is up!";
}

img.onerror = function()
{
    // If the server is down, do that.
    document.getElementById("miDiv").innerText = "Server is down!";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias he solucionado mi problema con tu ayuda gracias 

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález, si te sirvió la respuesta, recuerda marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: de nada, @AlejandroGonzález por favor recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada.